# React form with Formik error : Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, jsx, formik

Pretty straightforward question.
I am building a form with several "identical" rows with Formik. Each row is made of Name and Surname input + a button

The key (coming from the map index) is placed on outermost element

I got rid of **some boilerplate code** coming out of Formik (handleChange, handleBlur etc)  :

```
<Formik...>
            {({values}) => (
                <FieldArray name={"authors"}>{({push, remove}) => (
                    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        {values.authors.map((author, index) => (
                            <PropertySubmissionFields author={author} index={index}/>
                        ))}

                    </Form>
                )}
                </FieldArray>)}
        </Formik>
```

In `<PropertySubmissionFields>` the key (coming from the map index) is placed on outermost element (each row) :

```
return <Form.Row key={index}>
<Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridName">
    <Form.Label>Prénom</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control
        name={`authors[${index}].name`}

    />
    <ErrorMessage name={`authors[${index}].name`}>
        {msg => <div className="error-message">{msg}</div>}
    </ErrorMessage>
</Form.Group>
<Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridSurname">
    <Form.Label>Nom</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control
        name={`authors[${index}].surname`}
        value={author.surname}
    />
    {author.surname !== 'null' && <ErrorMessage name={`authors[${index}].surname`}>
        {msg => <div className="error-message">{msg}</div>}
    </ErrorMessage>}
</Form.Group>
<Form.Group>
    <br/>
    <Button as={Col} className="mt-2 ml-1" type="button"
            onClick={() => {
                alert("remove");
            }}>
        X
    </Button>
</Form.Group>
</Form.Row>
```

I can display the index (number 0, 1 etc) using the console.
However, I cannot see the key inside the DOM element (`Form.Row` is a displayed as a `<div>`

Any ideas ?

Comment: The `key` prop isn't added to the DOM.  Also, using the index for your key is not a good idea.

Comment: Any reason why index is not a good candidate ?

Comment: https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually once using `.map()` you need to add `key` attribute to each rendered element in order to avoid that warning message. So based on that you need do the following - adding `key` as:

```
{
  values.authors.map((author, index) => (
     <PropertySubmissionFields key={index} author={author} index={index}/>
  ))
}
```

See the added `key={index}` attribute in my suggested solution.

Read further about [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) in the documentation, especially the [**Keys** section](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys).